# Sanity check - why does this PHP MySql insert not work?

Tags: php, mysql, forms

Can you scan my code below and work out why the form doesn't successfully insert a record in to my MySql table 'users'?

insert.php:

```
<?php // insert.php
require_once 'login.php';
$con = mysqli_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password, $db_database);
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySql: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO users (name, email)
VALUES
('$_POST[name]]','$_POST[email]')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "1 record added";

mysqli_close($con;)
?>
```

index.html:

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>Hello!</h1>

<form action="insert.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name">
Email <input type="text" name="email">
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Login credentials stored in a separate login.php file.
Thanks!

Comment: Using MySQLi, but still injecting $_POST values directly into the query string..... use prepared statements/bind variables

Comment: `echo $sql;` does it contained expected values?

Comment: your code is invalid, `$_POST[name]]` there is a `]` more

Comment: Lovely => http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/

Comment: Let me tell you two things. First: When you have variables inside of "-quoted strings, you should wrap them inside of {}'s, for readability -- "{$_POST['foo']}". Second: You should protect against SQL injection attacks -- Google it.

Comment: What is the error you get from mysqli_error?

Comment: Sidenote: This line `mysqli_close($con;)` should be `mysqli_close($con);` misplaced semi-colon.

Answer (score 2):

You have an extra square bracket here

```
 ('$_POST[name]]',
               ^------- //Remove this from your SQL Query
```

You need to switch to [`PreparedStatements`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) seriously as the above code of yours is directly prone to SQL Injection.

Comment: Yep, plus the fact that, the method OP is using, is [`Open to SQL injection`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/)

Comment: Yeah @Fred-ii-, I mentioned it :) Thanks :)

Comment: While that is a typo it wouldn't cause the sql to fail, it would just add a `]` to the end of the name in the column.

Comment: Am wondering if OP's [`misplaced semi-colon`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21814586/sanity-check-why-does-this-php-mysql-insert-not-work#comment33013591_21814586) would have anything to do with this. @ShankarDamodaran

Answer (score 0):

Try to do: 
VALUES ('".$_POST[name]."','".$_POST[email]."')";
so... use mysqli_real_escape_string for sql injection as it:
example:
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);

and it is mysqli_close($con); not mysqli_close($con;)

Comment: using mysqli's prepared statements would be better then concatenating the values.

Comment: Yes he can, why wouldnt he be able to, the docs show how to use it, the tutorials on there use are searchable

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, this line `mysqli_close($con;)` has a misplaced semi-colon, which should read as `mysqli_close($con);`

Typo or not, it was posted that way, but I'm not betting my bottom dollar on it.

Plus, your present method is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/).

There was a slight syntax error in `$_POST[name]]` which should have read as `$_POST[name]` however, as Patrick Evans stated in a [`comment`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21814586/sanity-check-why-does-this-php-mysql-insert-not-work/21814989#comment33013479_21814604):

*"While that is a typo it wouldn't cause the sql to fail, it would just add a ] to the end of the name in the column."*

Use this method instead: (**PDO**) - it's safer.

```
<?php
/* Your Database Credentials */
$dbname = 'your_database';
$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';

$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$sql = "INSERT INTO users (name,
        email

        ) VALUES (
        :name, 
        :email)";

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

$stmt->bindParam(':name', $_POST['name'], PDO::PARAM_STR);       
$stmt->bindParam(':email', $_POST['email'], PDO::PARAM_STR); 

$stmt->execute(array(':name' => $_POST['name'],':email' => $_POST['email']));
if($stmt != false) {
    echo "Success!";
} else {
    echo "An error occured saving your data!";
}

?>
```

And your existing, with a few modifications:

```
<?php // insert.php
require_once 'login.php';
$con = mysqli_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password, $db_database);
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySql: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$name=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['name']);
$email=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['email']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO users (name, email)
VALUES
('$name','$email')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "1 record added";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```